# Daily summary reports on tickets in Trac

Tags: trac

There is any method to update  trac ticket dialy status in trac site, and how can we see the dialy  ticket status from trac project site, please help me...

Comment: I think you'll have better luck if asking at pm.stackexchange.com or at superuser.com. Actually, at here your question is invalid. It has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific in your question?  What exactly do you mean by "see the daily ticket status" and "update trac ticket daily status"?

If all you want is a summary of the tickets that were opened and closed each day, you can use the Timeline view to do just that (just configure it to only show ticket changes and not wiki changes, new changesets, etc).  You can use the RSS feed button at the bottom of the Timeline view to monitor ticket changes outside of Trac.